# Can't get NextJS ConfettiExplosion to work: Invalid Hook Call

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js

I am trying to use this package in my NextJS site: https://www.npmjs.com/package/@reonomy/react-confetti-explosion

Here is the basics of it...

```
class SelectedBet extends React.Component {
    //Some stuff

    render() {
    return (
        {this.props.bet && (
        <SubmitBet
            bet={this.props.bet}
        />
    )}
}
```

SubmitBet

```
//Confetti
import ConfettiExplosion from '@reonomy/react-confetti-explosion'

function Submit(props) {
//State and functions stuff....
return (
    <>
       <ConfettiExplosion />
       //More stuff
    </>
)}
```

Any reason why this is erroring:

```
Error: Invalid hook call. Hooks can only be called inside of the body of a function component. This could happen for one of the following reasons:
1. You might have mismatching versions of React and the renderer (such as React DOM)
2. You might be breaking the Rules of Hooks
3. You might have more than one copy of React in the same app
See https://reactjs.org/link/invalid-hook-call for tips about how to debug and fix this problem.
```

Comment: It looks like the error might be coming fomr your code. Does it work if you create a new page with only a `ConfettiExplosion` component in it?

Comment: See this issue and response: https://github.com/reonomy/react-confetti-explosion/issues/1#issuecomment-853885010

Comment: I can go {false && <ConfettiExplosion />} and the apge loads like that issue says but don't know how to fix it. The answer doesn't work

Comment: Please share your `App` or whichever component uses the `Submit />`

Comment: I'm not able to reproduce the issue with the exact same code. The issue is probably somewhere else in the code you're not showing us. Could you please provide a codesandbox (or similar) where you can see the same issue happening?

Comment: Did you find an answer for this ?

Answer (score 0):

It depends on how you use your `Submit`,

```
  const App = () => { 
    return flag ? <Submit /> : null
  }
```

This would work, but if you do this

```
  const App = () => {
    return Submit()
  }
```

Then it wouldn't work.

Comment: My <div><Submit /></div> is just in a component output like <-that

Comment: can you share your `Submit` usage, ex. the `App` component?

Comment: Does that edit help?

Comment: is `SubmitBet` same as `Submit` ? Try `return this.props.bet ? <Submit /> : null`. Don't use `&&`

Comment: Yeah submit it submitbet. Doesn't work sorry. Same error